# ssh client returning error "Couldn't apply options"

Tags: libssh

I am getting "Couldn't apply options" while connecting to a SSH server.

When I checked the source code of the library I found the following code in the client.c
which is returning the error.

```
ret = ssh_options_apply(session);

if (ret < 0) {
    ssh_set_error(session, SSH_FATAL, "Couldn't apply options");
    leave_function();
    return SSH_ERROR;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what are the possibilities that could result into this error ?

Answer (score 0):

That no options are set using ssh_options_set(). ssh_options_apply() does sanity checks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I don't know why but when I added this "optional" option to the libssh tutorial then it worked:

```
ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_USER, "random_username");
```

Put this before setting the hostname option in your main application.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled this problem a lot until I managed to solve it. libssh tries to set SSH_OPTIONS_SSH_DIR option which is basically the path where known_hosts file would be written and it fails. In previous versions of libssh the path was something like "C:/Users/your_user/" by default where ".ssh" folder was created with "known_hosts" file inside. In latest versions you need to specify this path by yourself. And also don't forget to set SSH_OPTIONS_USER too.

```
ssh_options_set(sshSession, SSH_OPTIONS_SSH_DIR, "C://temp");
ssh_options_set(sshSession, SSH_OPTIONS_USER, "user");
```

Hope this helps.